# Mysql Stored Procedure not working as expected

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a requirement to write a SP where -
1. Select the rows count which match the given where clause.
2. Loop on the row counts and execute the delete query with limit n, till the time row count is not 0.
3. Decrease the row count value by n.

SP written -

```
BEGIN 
DECLARE current_timestamp_millis BIGINT;
    DECLARE RETENTION_DAYS SMALLINT;
    DECLARE numRows BIGINT DEFAULT 0;

    -- No. of days to retain data for
    SET RETENTION_DAYS = 1;

    -- Current epoch timestamp in millis
    SET current_timestamp_millis = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())*1000; 

    -- SQL query to get the count of rows ,eligible to get deleted. 
    select count(*) as numRows from table1 where state = 2 AND end_time < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())*1000 - (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) ;
    -- Loop on the num of rows from above select query and delete the rows in chunks of 100
    WHILE(numRows >=0) 
    DO
    Insert into test_t values(current_time_millis);
    Delete from table1 where end_time < ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())*1000 - (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))) limit 100;
    SET numRows = numRows - 100;
    DO SLEEP(2);
    END WHILE;
END;
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting up numrows try select..into numrows.